# Notify Kafka Producer for every unconsumed Message from topic by the Kafka Consumer

Tags: spring

I want to build a project by using kafka in which two API, where one will be producer and another one will be consumer and also want to implement logic if consumer fails to consume message from topic within 10 seconds then notify producer with delay-error message.

```
package com.mykafka.demo.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.mykafka.demo.service.Producer;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/api")
public class RestControllerForKafkaMsg {

@Autowired
private Producer producer;

@GetMapping("/producerMsg")
public void getMsgFromClient(@RequestParam ("message") String 
message) {
producer.sendMsgToTopic(message);
}

}



package com.mykafka.demo.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Producer {

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

public void sendMsgToTopic(String message) {
    kafkaTemplate.send("@@@_topic", message);
}

public void notifyProducer(String allMessages) {
    
    System.out.println("Unconsumed messages: " + allMessages);
}

}




package com.mykafka.demo.service;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Consumer {

private final Set<String> consumedMessages = new HashSet<>();


@KafkaListener(topics = "@@@@_topic", groupId = "@@@@_Group", 
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")

public void listenToTopic(String recivedMessage) {
    System.out.println("The Message Recived is:- " + 
recivedMessage);
 consumedMessages.add(recivedMessage);
}

}
```

How to implement logic if consumer fails to consume message from topic within 10 seconds then notify producer with delay-error message.